# Should [import] tag be used for questions about code import statements?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation, meta-tags

There is an [import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import) tag (created in ~Aug 2008, 26.4k questions) which was originally intended for **data** import, but later on it was adopted for **code** import as well (such mention was added into tag wiki in Apr 2012, but not into excerpt). There is also an opposite [export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/export) tag for data only.

On the other hand, there are tags like:

- [python-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-import) (created in ~Mar 2009, 5.6k questions),
- [javascript-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-import) (created in ~Jan 2016, 107 questions)

specifically intended for code import in corresponding languages, but used less often with their language tags, and:

- [data-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-import) (created in ~Feb 2009, 360 questions)

for data.

Is [import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import) really the canonical tag for **code** import, despite its origin? Should it be used for this purpose? Should something be done about its dual meaning?